# PHP symfony2 bootstrap assetic:dump error

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I am trying to use twitter bootstrap in my symfony2.7 project. This is the content on my `composer.json` file:

```
"require": {   
    ...
    "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "dev-master",
    "leafo/lessphp": "0.4.0",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "3.0.*",
    "jquery/jquery":  "1.11.*"
},
```

Then I configure assetic as follows:

```
    lessphp:
         file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php
         apply_to: "\.less$"
    cssrewrite: ~
braincrafted_bootstrap:
    less_filter: lessphp
```

Then the console response is this one when I do the `assetic:dump`:

> PS D:\Web\job-bid> php app/console assetic:dump --force web
>
> Dumping all dev assets. Debug mode is on.
>
> 10:17:49 [file+] web/css/bootstrap.css
>     [Exception]   Failed to assign arg @list: line: 50
>
> assetic:dump [--forks FORKS] [--watch] [--force] [--period PERIOD]
>   [--] []
>   PS D:\Web\job-bid

What could the problem be?

**Edit:**
Well I have changed to the latest version of bootstrap 2 and it gives me a different error:

> PS D:\Web\job-bid> php app/console assetic:dump web --force Dumping
>   all dev assets. Debug mode is on.
>
> 16:43:18 [file+] web/css/bootstrap.css 16:43:19 [file+]
>   web/css/bootstrap_bootstrap_1.css 16:43:21 [file+]
>   web/css/bootstrap_form_2.css 16:43:21 [file+] web/js/bootstrap.js
>
> [RuntimeException]   The source file
>   "D:\Web\job-bid\app/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/js/transition.js" does
>   not exist.
>
> assetic:dump [--forks FORKS] [--watch] [--force] [--period PERIOD]
>   [--] []
>
> PS D:\Web\job-bid>

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK http://leafo.net/lessphp/ is not compatible with Boostrap 3 > 3.0.0, see https://github.com/leafo/lessphp/issues/503

see this more complete answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20914166/4989952

Comment: You should also update the BootstrapBundle version. Check [bundle compaibility section](https://github.com/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle#compatibility), you should use v1.4.* with bootstrap 2, not dev-master.